# Spring Bidirectional Relationship - Foreign Key not inserted

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I'm trying to create a service that will process emails and store in on the database.

At this moment I have the following entities on my project:

Mail:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Mail {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String messageId;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private MailAddress sender;

    private String inReplyTo;

    @NotNull
    private LocalDateTime receivedAt;

    private String subject;

    @Lob
    private String message;

    @NotNull
    private String ticketId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "mail", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<MailAttachment> attachments;
}
```

MailAttachment:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class MailAttachment {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Lob
    @NotNull
    private byte[] attachment;

    @NotNull
    private String fileName;

    @NotNull
    private String fileFormat;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private Mail mail;
}
```

MailAddress:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class MailAddress {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String address;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "sender")
    private List<Mail> mails;
}
```

Then I'm doing the following:

```
...
List<MailAttachment> attachmentList = new ArrayList<>(1);
...
MailAttachment mailAttachment = new MailAttachment();
mailAttachment.setAttachment(data);
mailAttachment.setFileFormat(fileFormat);
mailAttachment.setFileName(filename);

attachmentList.add(mailAttachment);
...
mail.setAttachments(attachmentList);
mailRepo.save(mail);
```

The problem is that the FK isn't being inserted on the mail_attachment table.
All tutorials that I saw did the same way I did.

I'm using Spring Boot 2.2.4.

Any ideas why?

Thanks

Comment: try to change this line `mail.setAttachments(attachmentList);` with this `mail.getAttachments().addAll(attachmentList);`

Comment: Makes no difference.

Comment: Explain what's really going on.

Comment: On the table Mail Attachment the FK for the mail isn't inserted.

Comment: try @ManyToOne  with cascadeType.

Comment: Didn't solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try adding to every mail attachment: mailAttachment.setMail(mail) ?